# How to change SQL Server date

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

We have just put an application into production which is hosted on AWS using their SQL Server RDS.
We have discovered that the database is set to UTC time, where our local development database isn't.
For example. I'm trying to insert a date of 2016-06-27 08:00. This works fine on our local server, but on AWS, the date is set to 2016-06-26 22:00

I'm trying to replicate the problem on our local server, and I changed the server's timezone to UTC, but the date gets inserted as 2016-06-27 08:00, but I should now expect it to be inserted as 2016-06-26 22:00.
Is there some SQL Server setting I need to change to have a date automatically converted to insert UTC?

Comment: try changing data and timezone of server where sql is installed ..

Comment: I tried changing the timezone on my dev server. My data still gets inserted as 2016-06-27 08:00, when I would expect it to be inserted as 2016-06-26 22:00

Comment: Modification of the time zone for RDS SQL Server DB instances is not supported by AWS because SQL Server uses the operating system time. The only known workaround is to create functions at the application level to offset the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql Server DateTime datatype doesn't know anything about timezone. The time inserted is determined by the application posting the time. So this issue is going to be in your application, not in the database.

My recommendation would be to either:

1. Store all DateTime's as UTC converting them in the application before saving
2. Use the DateTimeOffset type which stores the timezone information as well as the time

Comment: If its the application, why is the time inserted different on my development and production servers?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. And to help, I need to know a little bit about the application, not just about the database. And sample code that's doing the insert would be very helpful.